# How to style mui switch track thumb and change it's position?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, switch-statement

i'm trying to style my switch from material UI to look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIOoN.png)

and right now it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By44D.png)

as I see from inspect I need to change this bellow span to  translate(17px,6px)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8ZaY.png)

and I'm overwriting the switch styles using createTheme like this

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiSwitch: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root:{
            '&.MuiButtonBase-root':{
              transform:'translate(40px)'
            },
          },
          switchBase: {
            color: 'white', // thumb - unchecked
            
          },
          thumb: {
            width: 15, // set the desired width
            height: 15, // set the desired height
          },
          '.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiSwitch-thumb.Mui-checked': {
            transform: 'translateX(40px)', // transformation for checked
          },
          colorPrimary: {
            '&.Mui-checked': {
              color: 'white', // thumb - checked
            },
          },
          track: {
            opacity: 1, // track - unchecked
            backgroundColor: '#ED674B',
            width:'58px',
            height:'22px',
            borderRadius:'13px',
            '.Mui-checked.Mui-checked + &': {
              opacity: 1, // track - checked
              backgroundColor: '#BEE108',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

I can't find anything to effect the span that I want anyone can help?